# why firebase display data randomly and unordered?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

i don't know why when i get my data from the firebase will Display on the listview random and unordered i tryed many time with out any result

there is no problem with the data on fire base but on the phone display.

```
    fun AddToList(){
 mRef.child("MyPosts").child("TEST").addValueEventListener(object 
   :ValueEventListener{
  override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
      Toast.makeText(this@NewsList,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }

  override fun onDataChange(datap0: DataSnapshot?) {

      try {


    var td = datap0!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
          MyList.clear()
 for (key in td.keys){

var data = td[key] as HashMap<String,Any>
MyList.add(ForList(
        data["pic"] as String
        ,data["txt1"] as String
        ,data["txt2"] as String
        ,data["m1"] as String
        ,data["m2"] as String
        ,data["m3"] as String
)
)

adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
      }
      }catch (ex:Exception){
          Log.e("MyAPP","Error on you app 0000",ex)
      }
  }

 })
 }
```

[image: Firebase Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not asking for the data in any specific order: `mRef.child("MyPosts").child("TEST").addValueEventListener(...`. If you want the data in a specific order, you will have to specify that. For example, to get the child nodes in the order of their keys:

```
mRef.child("MyPosts").child("TEST").orderByChild().addValueEventListener(...
```

With this the `DataSnapshot` that is passed into `onDataChange` will contain the data in the order of the keys. But if you then get the value like this `datap0!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>` you are dropping any ordering information, since a map can't maintain the information about the ordering of the child nodes.

To process the data in the order you requested you should look over the child nodes of the `DataSnapshot` with:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
    MyList.clear()
    for (child: DataSnapshot? in snapshot.getChildren()) {
        var data = child!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
        ...
```